# How to prevent headings (<h1>) from taking up more width than they need?

Tags: html, css, width

If I define a heading like `<h1>`, its width is set to 100% by default.

Is there a way to make sure its width is set to the smallest value possible?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can give it `display: inline`. This will make it behave like any text element - the default for `<h1>` is `display: block`.

There are other ways: `float: left` for example, but I find this the simplest and the one with the fewest side effects.

Note that you will then probably have to add a `<br>` to ensure a line break after the `<h1>`.

Comment: or <br/> if it's XHTML. (No need to use float:left I think...)

Answer (score 23):

Instead of `display: inline`, give it `display: inline-block`. This will retain the block-like qualities of the h1 tag, except for the 100% width.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way to make sure its **width** is set to the **smallest value possible**?

I think that `width: fit-content;` is better.

https://jsfiddle.net/fqk1a2v6/

Comment: A following content still starts from the next line in Chrome browser...

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi you're right. But the question is about the width that the headings use, and **not** about the display configuration of it.

Comment: thank you! this also helps simplify centering...

Answer (score 4):

It's a block level element, so it follows the rules of `display:block`. You can set `display:inline`, which may do what you need or not, depending on the context.