# Why Padding right and left does not affect the border of h1?

Tags: html, css, header, border, padding

I'm struggling with this problem:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5pGQ.jpg)

I want the border padding of my header to be 1px left and right but although i put that in css file the border still takes all the screen horizontally...
I want my border to fit the text,not be expanded in that way.Thx if you can help.This is the html for h1:`<h1 title="they kidnapped me">Doing some testing here</h1><hr>`

Comment: you mean probably *margin* and not *padding*

Comment: if i enter margin-left:350px and margin-right:350px it shrinks it like i want the problem is when i resize the window it's a mess

Comment: you need to use `display:inline-block`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to prevent <H1>'s from taking up more width than they need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124355/how-to-prevent-h1s-from-taking-up-more-width-than-they-need).

Answer (score 0):

H1 is by default a block element which takes up the whole line. Make it inline and it only takes up what space the text takes.

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: #192e51;
}

.testing {
  border: 1px double white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: inline;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="testing"> Doing some testing here </h1>
</div>
```